# Eclipse run configuration argument with spaces

Tags: java, eclipse, vexi

I need to pass a parameter using spaces to an application I am running through Eclipse. In Windows, the following syntax works:

```
param="%Some Name%"
```

In Linux, that parameter is always passed as separate arguments to the Java code that is interpreting it.

With Bash, the following syntax works:

```
"param=%Some Name%"
```

i.e. if I copy the full command and run it in a terminal, it launches the application correctly and passes the parameter as a single argument.

In Eclipse, it still splits the argument around the space(s).

I have tried escaping the spaces with slashes ('\ '). I have tried replacing the quotes with single quotes. I have tried all 3 in all their possible combinations. I'm at a loss to explain/understand as to what Eclipse is doing here that it does differently in Windows.

It is also proving notoriously hard to Google/search.

To complicate matters further, this isn't a standard run configuration. It is using the VexiDev ([source here](https://sourceforge.net/p/vexi/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/tools/org.vexi.vexidev/)) Eclipse feature.

Comment: Did you get solution for this? If yes, can you please post as answer? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the trick is to make sure you are entering in a double quote in the Eclipse GUI, not a unicode smart quote which you get by default.

If instead of typing the double quote, you copy it from a terminal or plain text editor and paste it into the argument box, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the problem in my case. Note that instead of copying the quotes, you can also type them and then undo the "auto-correction" that turns the typed straight quote into a "smart" quote.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try encapsulating the **whole** property in quotes like this :

```
"-Dlog4j.configuration=/config location/log4j.properties"
```

This works on my machine.(Linux)

Comment: Yes, I did. (Stated in the Q but perhaps I could have been clearer.)

Comment: As this seems to be working in my existing set up (don't have the old set up to test) I have belatedly marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this, but I had to go around Eclipse and do it from the command line.

I found the file that contained the run configuration.

It was in the .metadata directory in the workspace and ends with ".launch"

For example something like:

`./workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/FetchTest.launch`

That file is an xml file.

It has a key entry for the VM arguments and in that entry you can specify characters using XML escaping.

So to do something like

`-ea -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dparam="Complicated Thing"`

alter the launch file with

`<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS" value="-ea -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dparam=&quot;Complicated Thing&quot;"/>`

Then I had to restart Eclipse to get it to notice the change.

Answer (score 1):

This took me a while to figure out too but I found the answer.
Place the Run Configuration arguments in single quotes like the example below with 3 arguments:

SVCNOW 'This is the summary'  'and this is the description'

Show Command Line will not show the double quotes but they will be there when you run the class.